# PHPUnit and curl wrong charset, cannot compare equal strings

Tags: php, curl, character-encoding, phpunit

i have a PHPUnit test with an assertion:
`$this->assertEquals(json_encode($expected), json_encode($result));`

The assertion fails because the strings differ in their encoding: (the diff is actually larger, from a large json object)

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'Wir holen Ihre P\u00e4ckchen im Wunschzeitraum ab.'
+'Wir holen Ihre P\u00c3\u00a4ckchen im Wunschzeitraum ab.'
```

I get the actual string from a curl request, the expected string is defined inside the php file as a string.

I use the following curl code to retrieve the JSON from a server:

```
$headers = array(
"GET /HTTP/1.1",
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1",
"Content-type: application/json;charset=\"utf-8\"",
"Accept: application/json",            
"Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5",
"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
"Accept-Charset: utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
"Keep-Alive: 300",      
"Connection: keep-alive");

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/frontend_test.php/api');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($some_data),
  CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
));
// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);

$result = json_decode($body);
```

What may be the cause of this?

Comment: the file is encoded as utf-8, and when i inspect an ajax call to that api it says it's utf-8

Comment: What is the hard coded PHP string you are using?  Did you store it is as UTF-8 as well, since the Expected string 'Wir holen Ihre P\u00e4ckchen im Wunschzeitraum ab.' is smaller, it might not be properly encoded as UTF-8. Did you use the UTF8_encode()?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: the php string is inside a big array, here is that part as it is in the php file: array("description"=>"Wir holen Ihre Päckchen im Wunschzeitraum ab.") I also tried to encode the result of both json_encodes to utf-8 using utf8_encode and iconv. doesn't change anything. Can it have something to do with utf-8 and utf-16? Seems to me that the larger version is using two bytes for the "ä" character whereas the other one may only be using one byte?

Comment: i found this website http://www.alorelang.org/doc/encodings.html where they say ```"\u00c3\u00a4".decode(Utf8)             -- Decode "ä" in UTF-8 to 16-bit Unicode``` I'm not entirely sure what that means though. And then there is this website which lists ```\u00E4``` as beinig uincode for ä too. http://javathreads.de/2008/10/die-wichtigsten-utf-8unicode-sonderzeichen-fuer-die-entwicklung-mit-facelets/. So are those different unicode versions or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so the solution is simple in my case: The PDO connection used the wrong charset. (The API retrieved the String in question from the database, which was not encoded properly) Dumb mistake

Comment: Not sure if you can accept your own answer, but you should try to help position this at the top for the future, in case other answers come along.